# Validate resources and generate getter code for iOS app in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I’m looking for a tool that can validate my images and fonts in a iOS application.

**Problem:**

We have a lot of different images and fonts in our application. Sometimes some of those files are replaced or renamed. We don’t get compile warnings or errors just missing images scattered around the app.

I guess this is part of `Objective C` dynamic nature but I would really like some static check here.

Does there exist any tools that can validate content or autogenerate getter code? (preferable open source)

Thanks!

Comment: If you keep your images and your Font files in same physical folder Duplication can be avoided.

Comment: Yes, but what if the image is removed, without anybody checking the code? then I will get nil images… That’s the problem I try to solve. Any ideas?

Comment: For images try Asset Catalogs; they can really help if you have lots of files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**warning: Shameless self promovation ahead:**

We have created a tool, IDAssetManager, (not open source, however), that creates a static interface to resources.
This tool integrates heavily with Xcode. It manages and organizes resources, and generates a class with getter code for images, font and colors.

It also comes with a `Xcode plugin` that allow you to preview images directly from the Xcode codeview:

[image]

The tool will also register fonts in the info.plist file.

To get the kind of validation you are looking for you will have to:

1. Add all images to IDAsssetManager
2. Use the getter code generated by the tool
3. Hit the refresh button on the tool.

You will now get compile warnings for all missing resources.

You can try it here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idassetmanager-lite-for-xcode/id830464758?mt=12

**Edit**

You can see a video of the tool in action [here](http://youtu.be/oCR9MVfCuFQ)

Comment: Thanks EsbenB. I have just tried the tool for a couple of hours and seems very promising!